# A long-running operation is being executed on the main thread. Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, parse-platform

In my `ProfileViewController` I have a query that retrieves the users profile picture which is stored as a PF File.

```
  var query = PFQuery(className:"Users")
    query.whereKeyExists("profilePicture")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if error == nil {

            self.userNameLabel.text = PFUser.currentUser().username

            if let imageFile = PFUser.currentUser().objectForKey("profilePicture") as? PFFile {
                if let data = imageFile.getData() {
                    self.profPic.image = UIImage(data: data)
                }
            }

        }
        else {
            println("User has not profile picture")
        }
    }
```

This is the only query in this view, I have another query in my Home page of my app that has all the posts of all the user. The error I am getting i s `A long-running operation is being executed on the main thread.` Followed by `Break on warnBlockingOperationOnMainThread() to debug.`

I don't know how to work around this especially since I need to do another query to get the current users post for there profile. Should I use something other than `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock`. Thanks.

Comment: Are you absolutely positive this is the source of the problem? No `...WithContentsOfURL` or `sendSynchronousRequest` lingering about? Nothing else that might be blocking the main thread? BTW, Instruments has a feature called "Record Waiting Threads" feature, to help identify these sorts of issues. Have you used that?

Comment: I have not used either WithContentsOfUrl or sendSynchronousRequest, can you explain this Instruments feature so I can use it thanks @Rob

Comment: See "Time Profiling" section of WWDC 2014 app [Improving Your App with Instruments](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/?id=418), about 18 min into the video. It's been covered before in other year's videos, too, but this is a good place to start. But danh has identified the source of the problem, so Instruments is probably not needed at this point. But next time you can use Instruments to find the source of the problem yourself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The warning is from the Parse sdk.  This part: `imageFile.getData()` is synchronous, and Parse is kind enough to warn you when using any of the blocking calls.  There are a couple varieties of `getDataInBackground`... available as alternatives.  [See them in the docs here](https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFFile.html#//api/name/getDataInBackground).

Comment: Thanks which method would you recommend? So I shouldnt use findObjectsWithBlock? @danh

Comment: getDataInBackground can work.  The next variety ...WithBlock: tells you when its done.  Another ...WithBlock:ProgressBlock: tells you when done, and % complete as you go.  (but remember this is the PFFile class, so not find objects but get data).

Answer (score 3):

To elaborate on @danh solution this is the updated source code and works perfectly fine, thanks @danh!

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    var query = PFQuery(className:"Users")
    query.whereKeyExists("profilePicture")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if error == nil {

            self.userNameLabel.text = PFUser.currentUser().username

            if let imageFile = PFUser.currentUser().objectForKey("profilePicture") as? PFFile {
            imageFile.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock { (data: NSData!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
                    self.profPic.image = UIImage(data: data)
                }
            }

        }
        else {
            println("User has not profile picture")
        }
      }
    }
```